# How can i create a user own function in eggplant tool

Tags: android, automation, eggplant

As am new to this eggplant tool.Can anyone tell me how can i create a user `own functions` to call some piece of code for recursive use.Actually am familiar with core java. I dint get syntax for creating own functions using eggplant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In eggPlant, the concept of functions is referred to [as "Handlers".](http://docs.testplant.com/?q=handlers)

A handler is basically a function. It takes parameters, returns values, etc. For example, the following function returns the Serial Number of an Android Device connected over ADB (I am assuming you are familiar with ADB).

```
to getConnectionInfo
    put the connectioninfo into connectionInfo
    put property DeviceSerialNumber of connectionInfo into deviceSerialNo
    return deviceSerialNo
end getConnectionInfo
```

To call this function and print the return value, you would do: `put getConnectionInfo()`

To modify the above function to take a Parameter, you'd add a line (just below the "to" line) : `Params param1,param2`

I like to create "Helper" scripts, which *only contain handlers.* I'll then call the handlers wherever I want, e.g.

Contents of Script "helper"

```
to Function1
// perform some action    
end Function1

to Function2
// perform some action
end Function2
...
```

And then to call the functions

```
put helper.Function1()
```

put helper.Function2()